# Robolectric (Android): Using ShadowLocationManager ? Is it configurable?

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, robolectric

I have been using Robolectric quite successfully up until now. I have an activity that gets the location manager. Now according to the documentation the robolectric framework incorporates a shadow class called "ShadowLocationManager" to make a kind of mock.

My question really is, how can I control this mock, can I control what will be returned? If so how?

Or do I have to create my "OWN" shadow class and implement "ShadowLocationManager".

I have been searching for documentation but I just can't find anything to confirm what I am asking.

If robolectric does contain a shadow for location manager how do I control what providers are enabled? I didn't want to implement my own shadow class if one already exists and can be configured and controlled.

Answer (score 5):

The shadow classes in Robolectric are substitutes of the various Android classes and can only be changed depending on their implemented functionality.

Looking at [the source for ShadowLocationManager](https://github.com/pivotal/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xtremelabs/robolectric/shadows/ShadowLocationManager.java), you have some methods you can use to tweak the behavior of the fake:

```
    public void setProviderEnabled(String provider, boolean isEnabled);
    public void setProviderEnabled(String provider, boolean isEnabled, List<Criteria> criteria);
    public boolean setBestProvider(String provider, boolean enabled);
    public boolean setBestProvider(String provider, boolean enabled, List<Criteria> criteria);
    public void setLastKnownLocation(String provider, Location location);
```

You can get the shadow instance for LocationManager with:

```
LocationManager instanceOfLocationManager = Robolectric.newInstanceOf(LocationManager.class);
ShadowLocationManager slm = Robolectric.shadowOf(instanceOfLocationManager);
```

Note: in the example I'm using Robolectric to create the instance of `LocationManager`. Depending on your test setup, this instance might come from your injection framework or directly from calling `Context.getSystemService(..)`. Bottom line is, make sure the instance in your test is the same instance used by the code that is being tested.

Comment: ahh, ok so once i have the instance of the shadown i can change it with setProviderEnabled for example? THis is great thats what i want but i do i pass it back or tell robolectric to use my instance, surley its not automatic...  I must have to send the instance to robolectric for it to use it, no?

Comment: now its begginign to sink in :-)  So i can make an instance but just unsure how to send that instance to Robolectric so that it uses my shadow/mock

Comment: SOrry, where do i get instanceOfLocationManager from?, if i am in my test class.

Comment: @Martin - added some more to the example. Also: yes, it is automatic, the shadow instance will be created by Robolectric. The shadow instance is stored as part of the instance of `LocationManager`.

Comment: You get an instance of location manager with something like `LocationManager = (LocationManager) Robolectric.application.getSystemService(Application.LOCATION_SERVICE);`.  If you are using a DI framework or something else, it might get a little more complicated.